# Unable to display delete and cancel button on editing a contact in ABPersonViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

Hyiee I am new to Objective-C. I am trying to edit a person contact info but action Sheet containing delete and cancel button is not appearing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can display anything over the top of an ABPersonViewController, however, have a look at the ABDelete category here that enables deletion - https://github.com/shrtlist/ABDelete/

Comment: It Worked for me.Thanks danielbeard